# Kubernetes is always forwarding the request to same pod

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 1 control-plane and 1 worker, the worker has in it 3 pods. The pods and service with Type: NodePort are on the same node. I was expecting the service to load balance the requests between the pods but looks like all the requests are always getting forwarded to only one pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30002
  selector:
    app: web
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-app
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web-app
        image: webimage
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "0.5"
          requests:
            cpu: "0.5"
~
```

Comment: Do you also have a load balancer in place?

Comment: no, I'm using kind.

Comment: How did you managed to test it? I tested you deployment and service on my lab and it's load balancing as expected. You have access to your master node console? If yes, please update your question with the output for `sudo iptables-save | grep web-svc | grep probability`.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior if your requests have persistent TCP connection. Try adding `"connection":"close"` in your HTTP header.